# Port forwarding on Linux

Tags: linux, port-forwarding

I am trying to get a port forwarded on my Linux machine, and I think I do everything right, but it doesn't work.

The `iptables-save` command on the server looks like this:

```
[root@wcs ~]# iptables-save
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.7 on Tue Sep 16 11:25:57 2014
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [84359:14594571]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [3:180]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [84251:14540765]
COMMIT
# Completed on Tue Sep 16 11:25:57 2014
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.7 on Tue Sep 16 11:25:57 2014
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [4:564]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
-A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8080 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.202.64.118:80 
-A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.202.64.118:80 
COMMIT
# Completed on Tue Sep 16 11:25:57 2014
```

The server has two interfaces; `eth0` with IP address `10.60.172.7` and `eth1` with `10.202.64.100`. I can connect to `10.60.172.7` from the outside world, and want to route a port to the other network (specifically that one IP).

I have IP fowarding on:

```
[root@wcs ~]# cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/eth0/forwarding
1
[root@wcs ~]# cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/eth1/forwarding
1
```

Firewall and SELinux are disabled.

When I do an `nmap` from the "outside", I get `filtered` on those forwarded ports. What could be the issue?

Comment: Firewall and SELinux are disabled??? Iptables is the firewall.

Comment: With "disabled" I mean I used sysconfig to disable it, meaning it accepts on all ports. I *think* that is also shown by all the `ACCEPT`s in `iptables-save`.

Comment: "cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward" also shows 1? Does the 10.202.64.118 system know how to route those packets back to the client? (I.e. do you perhaps need SNAT in addition to the DNAT.) Try tcpdump -c100 -ni eth1 port 80 to see if packets are indeed being sent towards the .118 system (the -c100 limits tcpdump to 100 packets in case you're on a very busy network).

Comment: Don't you need a forward rule in your `filter` section such as `[0:0] -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o eth1 -j ACCEPT` ?
`

Comment: @MarcusRickert I don't think so, because `FORWARD` is set to `ACCEPT` all.